# C# Booking room Check available

Tags: c#, sql

I've a problem with my assignment about room booking online.

I've 3 tables like below:

Table `Room`:

[image]

Table`BookingHeader`:

[image]

Table `BookingItem`:

[image]

And I've a problem with this code. It's no error but the room can't booking for other booking. When room is reserve with `booking_id` with date it's never return.

```
for (int countt = 1; countt <= totalcc; countt++)
{
    DataTable dtRoom = new DataTable();
    string Sql = ("SELECT TOP 1 rooms.Room_ID FROM TB_MAS_Room rooms 
WHERE rooms.Room_ID NOT IN(SELECT t1.Room_ID FROM TB_TRA_BookingItem t1 
INNER JOIN TB_TRA_BookingItem t2 ON t1.Room_ID = t2.Room_ID 
INNER JOIN TB_TRA_BookingHeader t3 ON t2.Booking_ID = t3.Booking_ID 
WHERE not ([DateOut] < t3.DateIn or [DateIn] > t3.DateOut))");//new
    SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand(Sql,con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCom);
    da.Fill(dtRoom);
    if(dtRoom.Rows.Count>0)
    {
        SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TB_TRA_BookingItem 
([Booking_ID],[BookingItemID],[Room_ID]) 
VALUES('"+ id +"','"+ countt +"','"+ dtRoom.Rows[0]["Room_ID"].ToString() +"')",con);
        sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    else
    {
        //if room not avialable
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

So, How I can do?

Please explain what I miss in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Why You Are not Updating The Status Of that Room To "Booked" or 1-0 
You Should Add a Column to Table Room
RoomStatus Bit,

And When You Insert A New Booking Update This Row by A simple Query 
Update TableName Set RoomStatus = 1 where Room_ID = Get_Room_ID_FromBooking

After Doing this You Would Be able To Check the Room is Booked Or Not